# Android Studio emulator gets stuck minimised in task bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Android Studio on Ubuntu 16.04. The AVD emulator starts fine, and I can install apks on it. However, if I change to a different workspace, minimise the emulator, or even click on another window, backrounding the emulator, it appears to minimise(only visible in the task bar), and from then on, it will not maximise again. Clicking on it in the bottom task bar makes it appear for a split second before minimising again. I haven't had this problem with any other window. Anyone know how to fix it?

So far I have tried:

- Setting the emulator window to always stay on top 
  answer to install various libs that have helped people with similar AVD problems
- Starting the emulator from the command line

Answer (score 3):

For Windows use:
If a window won’t maximize, press Shift+Ctrl and then right-click its icon on the taskbar and select Restore or Maximize, instead of double-clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom left corner of Android studio, there is a squared icon that allows you to see all Panles. it includes also Emulator. By selecting it, I was able to have my Emulator back on screen (view mode: float).

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround. By clicking into the window menu from the very top left of the emulator window, I set the emulator to both 'always be on bottom' AND always appear in all workspaces. This way, switching workspaces doesn't have any effect on the emulator, and keeping it to the bottom layer means I can open other programs in other workspaces and not have the emulator in the way. I just can't ever minimise it. It's not ideal, but at least I can do my work!