# Why is my Android Studio emulator screen only visible in the task bar

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10, emulation, virtual-device-manager

I am trying to run my Android Studio applications using my emulator. But when i try to run it emulator only shows up like this:
[Emulator stuck in taskbar - Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AZK8.png)
I have created multiple Virtual devices though..and all of these have same issue. Sadly, I have no control over my emulator except if i hover over it then only the screen for emulator is displayed but the view is minimized and as soon as I move my mouse away or even if i double click the screen nothing happens. By the way i'm using windows 10 and Android Studio 3.6.3. My problem is similar to [Android Studio emulator gets stuck minimised in task bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481084/android-studio-emulator-gets-stuck-minimised-in-task-bar). But this question has not been helpful to me in fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabye it opens somewhere else: Try the following:

```
    - Press SHIFT+CTRL

     - Right Click on the Program showing up in the taskbar.

     - Select the "Move" Window option

     - Use the keyboard (Left Arrow/Right Arrow)  <-/ -> keys to move the window to the center of the screen.

     - Try holding down the left arrow key  for a while to see the Window outline. Try moving right/up/down if the window outline is still not visible.

     - Hit enter when you can see the Window outline  move  to the center of the screen.

It appears that the desktop extends beyond the Screen Display and the program window seems hidden. Moving the Window either to the Left / Right / Top/ Bottom of the screen helps.
```

Coppied from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4e5bc3e6-a5c7-4ce7-bb66-29b78a7ce020/application-stays-minimized-in-the-taskbar?forum=itprovistadesktopui).

Comment: Not really! I already tried this "shift+ctrl+right mouse click" trick but for my emulator(in the taskbar) no menu pops up. Sadly, I have no control over my emulator except if i hover over it then only the screen for emulator is displayed but the view is minimized and as soon as I move my mouse away or even if i double click the screen nothing happens. I will also update this issue in my question aswell.