# How can I return Emulator to taskbar as default?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, emulation

I didn't know what I've made to make the emulator like this. I want to get it back as it was in the taskbar.

[image]

Comment: check these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481084/android-studio-emulator-gets-stuck-minimised-in-task-bar   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115503/why-is-my-android-studio-emulator-screen-only-visible-in-the-task-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new embeded emulator style. To revert back, go to **File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator** and uncheck "**Launch in a tool window**" and save

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it, It works!

Comment: Happy to help. Accept the solution since it works